# Some help needed on grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am trying to find alphanumeric string including these two characters "/+" with at least 30 characters in length.

I have written this code,

```
grep "[a-zA-Z0-9\/\+]{30,}" tmp.txt
```

cat tmp.txt

```
> array('rWmyiJgKT8sFXCmMr639U4nWxcSvVFEur9hNOOvQwF/tpYRqTk9yWV2xPFBAZwAPRVs/s
ddd73ZEjfy+airfy8DtqIqKI9+dd 6hdd7soJ9iG0sGs/ld5f2GHzockoYHfh
+pAzx/t17Crf0T/2+8+reo+MU39lqCr02sAkcC1k/LzyBvSDEtu9N/9NHicr jA3SvDqg5s44DFlaNZ/8BW37fGEf2rk13S/q68OVVyzac7IT7yE7PIL9XZ/6LsmrY
KEsAmN4i/+ym8be3wwn KWGYaIB908+7W98pI6qao3iaZB
3mh7Y/nZm52hyLa37978f+PyOCqUh0Wfx2PL3vglofi0l
QVrOM1pg+mFLEIC88B706UzL4Pss7ouEo+EsrES+/qJq9Y1e/UGvwefOWSL2TJdt
```

this does not work, Mainly I wanted to have minimum length of the string to be 30

Comment: What's your expected output? Did you want to match the whole line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the syntax of `grep`, the repetition braces need to be backslashed.

```
grep -o '[a-zA-Z0-9/+]\{30,\}' file
```

If you want to constrain the match to lines containing only matches to this pattern, add line-start and line-ending anchors:

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9/+]\{30,\}$' file
```

The  `-o` option in the first command line causes `grep` to only print the matching part, not the entire matching line.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess, ^ is for starting of the line and $ is for the end of line. It( search pattern) need not start from the beginning of the line and need not end with $ (i.e end of line). Will it work if this pattern is followed & proceeded by other strings also ?

Comment: no, if you want only the matched word then you could use `grep -o '[a-zA-Z0-9/+]\{30,\}' file`

Comment: The backslashed braces are what solved the OP's problem.  Anchoring the search was not specified in the question and will wreck matching on lines which also contain other stuff.  See the OP's comment above.  Removing the anchors should suffice if printing the whole line is desired.

Answer (score 1):

The repetition operator is not directly supported in Basic Regular Expression syntax. Use `grep -E` to enable Extended Regular Expression syntax, or backslash the braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
grep -e  "^[a-zA-Z0-9/+]\{30,\}" tmp.txt
```

---

```
grep -e "^[a-zA-Z0-9/+]\{30,\}" tmp.txt


+pAzx/t17Crf0T/2+8+reo+MU39lqCr02sAkcC1k/LzyBvSDEtu9N/9NHicr jA3SvDqg5s44DFlaNZ/8BW37fGEf2rk13S/q68OVVyzac7IT7yE7PIL9XZ/6LsmrY
3mh7Y/nZm52hyLa37978f+PyOCqUh0Wfx2PL3vglofi0l
QVrOM1pg+mFLEIC88B706UzL4Pss7ouEo+EsrES+/qJq9Y1e/UGvwefOWSL2TJdt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man grep
```

Read up about the difference between between regular and extended patterns. You need the `-E` option.